# How do you append a number for duplicate records in a mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I think the solution is somewhat easy, of course it is eluding me.

I have two tables and am Joining them on a field with identical values:

example records:

```
art0001,
art0001,
art0001,
art0002,
art0002,
art0003
```

**What I want to do is to append a number to count every duplicate and echo it out like this:**

```
art0001-1,
art0001-2,
art0001-3

art0002-1,
art0002-2,

art0003-1
```

I came up with this code, but the output just adds a number, but does not restart when a new duplicate is found.

```
$query = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM product_image JOIN my_art ON product_folder = product_code" );
if( !$query ) {
     die( mysql_error() ); 
}
$row =  mysql_fetch_array($query);


$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    if($row['COUNT(base_folder)'] < 1 && $row['image_type'] == 'B' && $row['view'] == 'FF') {
        echo $row['base_folder']."-".$i++;
        echo "<br />";
    }

}
```

Can anyone please help me and tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: This can't be your real code. It reads calculated columns that are not in the SQL query. It doesn't even compile.

Comment: @Álvaro PHP code never compiles, really. But indeed this isn't the actual code: the code uses a COUNT(base_folder) that isn't in the query. Probably a simplification.

Comment: I guess that may be why it does not work. The base_folder table actually has the columns id, base_folder, image_type, and view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep a counter for each 'product' individually, you'll have to check that the product is still the same in the loop, or if this another product. Mind you: the order by clause in the query is needed for this to work.

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM product_image JOIN my_art ON product_folder = product_code ORDER BY product_folder" );
if( !$query ) {
     die( mysql_error() ); 
}
$row =  mysql_fetch_array($query);

$i = 0;
$last = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    if( $row['COUNT(base_folder)'] < 1 && $row['image_type'] == 'B' && $row['view'] == 'FF' ) {
        if( $last !== $row['basefolder'] ) {
             $i = 0;
        }
        echo $row['base_folder']."-".$i++;
        echo "<br />";
        $last = $row['basefolder'];
    }
}
```

Comment: @GGcupie In which case, it's generally considered "polite" on StackOverflow to accept a valid answer as the answer to your question.

Comment: oh I am sorry, I am new on this site let me do that!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array to keep track of the item count:

```
<?php

$test_data = array(
    'art0001',
    'art0001',
    'art0001',
    'art0002',
    'art0002',
    'art0003',
);

$item_count = array();
foreach($test_data as $item){
    if( isset($item_count[$item]) ){
        $item_count[$item]++;
    }else{
        $item_count[$item] = 1;
    }

    echo $item . '-' . $item_count[$item] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function for taking an array with duplicate values and appending a number to only the duplicate names.

```
            Array
            (
                [0] => samename
                [1] => namesame
                [2] => samename
                [3] => namename
                [4] => namename
                [5] => notsame
                [6] => samename
            )

            Array
            (
                [0] => samename
                [1] => namesame
                [2] => samename(2)
                [3] => namename
                [4] => namename(2)
                [5] => notsame
                [6] => samename(3)
            )       


            function uniqueNames($array){
                        $alreadyoccured=array();
                        $newarray=array();
                        foreach($array as $arr){
                            if(array_key_exists($arr,$alreadyoccured)){
                                $alreadyoccured[$arr]=$alreadyoccured[$arr]+1;
                                $newarray[]=$arr.'('.$alreadyoccured[$arr].')'; 
                            }else{
                                $alreadyoccured[$arr]=1;
                                $newarray[]=$arr; 
                            }
                        }

                        return $newarray; 

                    }
```